# US equivalent of "my tupp'orth"

Tags: idioms, american-english, popular-refrains

Although the phrase is now somewhat outdated, in British English we sometimes say "I'd like to add my tupp'orth to the debate" - meaning "I'd like to add a few thoughts of my own..." The phrase literally means (colloquially) "my tuppenny worth", i.e. "my two pennies' worth".

What would be the nearest equivalent in US English? (It doesn't necessarily have to be a phrase involving coinage - I'm just looking for a widely-used idiom.)

Comment: To add my two cents....

Comment: Ah, yes! Do people say: "...add my two cents to the debate" or would it just be "...add my two cents"?

Comment: Yes, but "my two cents' worth".

Comment: The shorter: "I'd like to add my two cents."

Comment: There are ***many*** variations on this theme.  Too many to list probably.

Answer (score 4):

A common AmE equivalent expression is:

***[put your two cents in](http://put%20your%20two%20cents%20in%20also%20put%20in%20your%20two%20cents%20to%20give%20your%20opinion%20She%20believes%20it's%20her%20duty%20to%20vote%20and%20put%20her%20two%20cents%20in.%20See%20also:%20cent,%20put,%20two%20Cambridge%20Dictionary%20of%20American%20Idioms%20Copyright%20%C2%A9%20Cambridge%20University%20Press%202003.%20Reproduced%20with%20permission.)*** also ***put in your two cents***:

> - to give your opinion
>
>   - *She believes it's her duty to vote and put her two cents in.*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any difference in terms of register (- i.e. how formal this sounds in comparison to "add my two cents")? (Or is there any other difference - might one (or both) reflect a more regional usage, for example?)

Comment: Anything with “two cents” would be considered informal.

Comment: Often the American version is more of an afterthought, i.e. it appears after the opinion, as a sort of apology Blah blah blah... Well, that's my two cents'.